# Returning large files (1GB +) from a Delphi server

Tags: javascript, delphi, server

I have a web server developed with Delphi 10.4 Sydney. The server uses Mormot and Moustache.

It serves an HTML web page to the client's browser, allowing the client to access the server database after authentication and return JSON to the client, which uses Moustache for presentation.

The HTML page allows for the backup of a file to be initiated via calling a backup routine on the server. The Delphi server app then creates the backup in, say `C:\temp\backup.zip`.

I want to force the download of `C:\temp\backup.zip` via the HTML page, but I do not want to provide access to the `C:\temp` folder via HTML by opening up port 80 when I already have authenticated access to the Delphi server app. I need to transfer the file from the `C:\Backup\backup.zip` location to the HTML page, which would then save the file locally to the file location on the client's compuer: `C:\temp\backup.zip`.

Is there a way of having the web page stream the zip file to the client, via the Delphi Mormot server?

I was thinking JavaScript, but all the Javascript examples I see expect the `C:\temp` folder to be accessible via `http://IPADRESS/temp/backup.zip`.

Comment: No need to write every sentence into its own paragraph and to not use a question mark at the end of a question. Also it's not about ZIP files, only about files. I'm sure you can open/serve a file for download unbound to its location in the file system.

Comment: The best way to handle this is to have the server expose access to a different URL, like `http://server/getbackup`, and when an authenticated client requests that URL, the server can then send the contents of the zip file to the client. However, the server has no control over what the client does with that content. The user will have to choose to save the content to where they want, as it is downloading. For instance, the server can include certain HTTP headers to suggest to the browser that the content is an attachment, so the browser will prompt the user to save the file.